# Transformation applied to system without symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Imagine we have a central potential which gives us the Hamiltonian of the form:
$$\hat H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 +V(r)$$
In general this is not symmetric under translation. But let us say that I do naively perform a translation on this system, which of my predictions will go wrong and why?

Comment: Not really sure I understand "which of my predictions will go wrong and why". Why should they go wrong? If you transform this Hamiltonian by translating it, you will get the same Hamiltonian, just written in different coordinates, and so it will have a slightly different (and extremely hard to work with) mathematical form, but you can ("can" as in "theoretically can") still diagonalize it and get eigenstates, and they will be the right ones but in different coordinates.

Comment: @march take a look at page 6 of this http://hepwww.rl.ac.uk/Haywood/Group_Theory_Lectures/Lecture_1.pdf it gives an example of the classical equivalent of what I am talking about.